# Jupyter: deploy from local to cloud environment?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a personnal IA project that requires a good computing power (training text recognition [EasyOCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) with new data).

It takes too much time to train (even more without CUDA GPU optimisation which I have difficulties to set up).

So I want to use [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/).

Problem, I don't know how to pass my project and make it work on Google Colab, I have hundreds of images and it ask me to accept every dowload ! And I can't download folder with stuff on it !

How can I pass a .zip project folder or just a project folder and make it works on a notebook ? (like Google Colab)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Github Settings -> SSH and GPG keys -> Developers settings -> Personnal Access Tokens
!git clone https://USERNAME:TOKEN@github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```